# Simple Hangman game - 3 questions

Tags: java

Okay so this is my first project in Java. I'm so happy it finally works, especially because I've put much more time in it than I thought I will have to.

I have 3 questions though

1. I had to put 'static' in front of variables that are shared by all methods, because without it I had "non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static content" errors. How does it affect my script, does it have any meaning in practice?
2. Why I cannot change package name? It is not mentioned anywhere but the first line of the script
3. The game works, but there is one more little thing I forgot about, and I don't really know how to solve this problem.

This part decides if the player won or not

```
 if  (wordList.size() == 6) {
                System.out.println("\nYou won, congratulations! \n");
                break;
 }
```

The thing is, I had to write number '6' because I acknowledged that in my codeword 'Economy' there are 2 letters 'o', so if will make it like this

```
wordList.size() == word.length()
```

it won't work (it would work if there wouldn't be 2 same letters in a codeword)

Full code:

```
package hangman;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Hangman {
        static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        static ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        static ArrayList<Character> wordListChar = new ArrayList<Character>();
        static String word = "economy";
        static int answers = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("************");
        System.out.println("* Hangman *");
        System.out.println("************");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");


        while (true)  {

        System.out.println("Choose a letter! \n");
        String command = reader.nextLine(); 
            if (command.length() == 1) {

                if (!wordList.contains(command)) {
                   printWord(command);
                   guess(command);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("You already guessed this letter! \n");
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Write only 1 letter!");
            }

            if  (wordList.size() == 6) {
                System.out.println("\nYou won, congratulations! \n");
                break;
            }

            if  (answers == 6) {
                System.out.println("\nThis guy is dead, You lost! \n");
                break;
            }

        }

    }

public static void guess(String command) {

      if (word.contains(command)) {
          System.out.println("\nYes, the letter - " + command + " - is in the word!\n" );


      } else {
          System.out.println("\nThe letter - " + command + " - is NOT in the word!\n" );
          answers++;
          hangHim();
      }

}

public static void hangHim() {
    if (answers == 1) { 
                System.out.println("         ____________");
                System.out.println("        |      |     |");
                System.out.println("        |      O     |");
                System.out.println("        |            |");
                System.out.println("        |            |");
                System.out.println("        |            |");
                System.out.println("         ____________");
                System.out.print("\n");
    } 
    else if (answers == 2) { 
                System.out.println("         ____________");
                System.out.println("        |      |     |");
                System.out.println("        |      O     |");
                System.out.println("        |      |     |");
                System.out.println("        |            |");
                System.out.println("        |            |");
                System.out.println("         ____________");
                System.out.print("\n");
    } 
    else if (answers == 3) { 
                System.out.println("         ____________");
                System.out.println("        |      |     |");
                System.out.println("        |      O     |");
                System.out.println("        |     -|     |");
                System.out.println("        |            |");
                System.out.println("        |            |");
                System.out.println("         ____________");
                System.out.print("\n");
    } 
    else if (answers == 4) { 
                System.out.println("         ____________");
                System.out.println("        |      |     |");
                System.out.println("        |      O     |");
                System.out.println("        |     -|-    |");
                System.out.println("        |            |");
                System.out.println("        |            |");
                System.out.println("         ____________");
                System.out.print("\n");
    } 
    else if (answers == 5) { 
                System.out.println("         ____________");
                System.out.println("        |      |     |");
                System.out.println("        |      O     |");
                System.out.println("        |     -|-    |");
                System.out.println("        |     /      |");
                System.out.println("        |            |");
                System.out.println("         ____________");
                System.out.print("\n");
    } 
    else if (answers == 6) { 
                System.out.println("         ____________");
                System.out.println("        |      |     |");
                System.out.println("        |      O     |");
                System.out.println("        |     -|-    |");
                System.out.println("        |     / \\    |");
                System.out.println("        |            |");
                System.out.println("         ____________");
                System.out.print("\n");


    } 

}

public static void printWord(String command) {

       if (word.contains(command)) {


                        wordList.add(command);

                        String command2 = command;
                        char commandChar = command2.charAt(0);
                        wordListChar.add(commandChar);

                       // System.out.println(wordList.size());
                       // System.out.println(wordListChar.size());

                        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                            char letter = word.charAt(i);

                            if (command.charAt(0) == letter) {
                                System.out.print(letter); 
                            }
                           else if (wordListChar.contains(word.charAt(i))) {
                                System.out.print(letter);
                            }
                            else {
                                System.out.print('*');

                            }
                        }
                      System.out.print("\n\n");



            }    
    }




}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Static keyword implies that class is owning your field, not the object itself. It means that this field will be not created with each object creation, instead, there will be just one field shared across all objects of a given type. You had to do this only in your main application class coz of the main method being static.
2. You can, you just need to make changes in directories structure accordingly.
3. Get the word, skip the same letters, count the length and then check it against your guessed ones.